# How to convert json to php array and use foreach on it?

Tags: php, json, telegram-bot

I've build a Telegram bot and want to replying any message that is sending to my bot. I used getUpdates method and received a JSON object. Now I want to extract any chat_id from this and send a message to it using sendMessage method.
Please help me how to use a foreach for this.
The below is my JSON object:

`{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":709393586,
"message":{"message_id":60,"from":{"id":123456789,"first_name":"Ameer","last_name":"Mousavi","username":"ameer_mousavi"},"chat":{"id":123456789,"first_name":"Ameer","last_name":"Mousavi","username":"ameer_mousavi"},"date":1436038917,"text":"hi"}}]}'`

Sorry for beginner question ;) I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: see http://docs.php.net/json_decode

Comment: @VolkerK I saw that but I cannot figure out that :(

Comment: There's nothing in the JSON literal (snippet?) you've posted that would lend itself to foreach, imo. `result` is an array, so it might be used with foreach. But in the given example it contains only one element ....

Comment: Thank you @VolkerK! I found it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$response = json_decode(data(), true);
if ( !$response['ok'] ) {
    die('not ok');
}
else {
    foreach($response['result'] as $result) {
        echo $result['update_id'], ' ', $result['message']['chat']['id'], "\r\n";
    }
}


function data() {
    return '{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":709393586,
"message":{"message_id":60,"from":{"id":123456789,"first_name":"Ameer","last_name":"Mousavi","username":"ameer_mousavi"},"chat":{"id":123456789,"first_name":"Ameer","last_name":"Mousavi","username":"ameer_mousavi"},"date":1436038917,"text":"hi"}}]}';
}
```

prints

```
709393586 123456789
```

i.e. the update_id and the id of the chat element.

Comment: Please Help me this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Here is the code:

```
`$obj = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($obj["result"] as $key => $value) {
    $temp_chat_id =  $value["message"]["chat"]["id"];
    sendMessage($temp_chat_id, "Hi");
}`
```

Comment: Please Help me this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41519495/how-to-solve-disturbance-in-my-bot-in-c