# How to solve disturbance in my bot in c#?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I made a telegram Bot. In fact, the bot is a game, play guess certain words.But the problem is when I add robots to two different groups (as an administrator) or Two user-Telegram, separately ،use of the bot and start bot,Puts the impact of what they played together.Game one person is caused a disturbance in next person game. for example: if john start my bot in Mobile and desired_word for john is Newyork and length=7 ,when sara start my bot in Mobile. Len_desiredwords for john for example Become to 5 .

library = NetTelegramBotApi 4.0.0
vs = 2013 v4;

Do not know what to do.

code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NetTelegramBotApi;
using NetTelegramBotApi.Requests;
using NetTelegramBotApi.Types;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WordsBot
{


 class Program
  {
   private static string Token =".........";
   private static ReplyKeyboardMarkup Menu1;

     static void Main(string[] args)
        {

           Task.Run(() => RunBot());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    public static async Task RunBot()
        {

            var bot = new TelegramBot(Token);
           // var updates = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetUpdates() { Offset = offset });



            var me = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetMe());
            Console.WriteLine("User Name is {0}", me.Username);
            long offset = 0;
            int whilecount = 0;
            while (true)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("while is {0}", whilecount);
                whilecount += 1;

                var  updates = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetUpdates() { Offset = offset });

                Console.WriteLine("Update Count is {0} ", updates.Count());
                Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------");
                try
                {



     string desired_word = "";
     int Len_desiredwords = 0 ;
     char [] blank1='';
     string b1="";
     string [] blank2="";
     foreach (var update in updates)
       {
        var text = update.Message.Text;
        offset = update.Id + 1;
         if (Text == "/start")
         {
            ds_GetDersiredWords = DAL.Get_DersiredWords();
             dt_GetDersiredWords = ds_GetDersiredWords.Tables[0];
             desired_word=dt_GetDersiredWords.Rows[0][1].tostring();// get word random of db 
             Len_desiredwords = desired_word.Length; // count charachter of word
             blank1 = desired_word.tochararray();// string to chararray

             for (int ii=0;ii<Len_desiredwords;ii+)// insert charachter '_' in blank1
             {
                  blank1 [ii] = '_';
             }
             for (int jj=0;jj<Len_desiredwords;jj++ )
             {
                  blank2 = blank2 + blank1 [jj];
             }

             var q = new SendMessage(update.Message.Chat.Id, "please Enter one charachter\n desired_word ="+blank2 ); // send to user id in telegram message.
             await bot.MakeRequestAsync(q);
                         continue;
          }
          else if (Text.length==1) // if Text = one Character
          {
             for (int xx=0;xx<Len_desiredwords;xx++)
             {
                  if (blank1 [xx] =system.convert.char(text))// check if charachter entered is in blank1 chararray? or no?
                  {
                      correct= true;
                      index1 = xx;
                      blank1[index1] = System.Convert.ToChar(text);
                      for(int yy= 0 ;yy<Len_desiredwords;yy++)
                      {

                      blank2 = blank2 + blank1 [yy];
                      }

                  }
                  else
                   {
                      continue;
                   }

              }

              if (correct==true)
                {
                        var q = new SendMessage(u.Message.Chat.Id,(update.Message.Chat.Id, "correct\n please Enter Next charachter\n desired_word ="+blank2 ");
                        await bot.MakeRequestAsync(q);
                        continue;
                 }

              else if(correct!=true)  
                {


                  var q = new SendMessage(u.Message.Chat.Id,(update.Message.Chat.Id, "incorrect\n please Enter Next charachter\n desired_word ="+blank2 ");
                  await bot.MakeRequestAsync(q);
                  continue;
                }         

           }
          else
           {
             continue;
            }
        }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       continue;
   }
}




}
```

example :

john run and start my bot , my bot send for john in telegram:

```
- Welcome to Guess the word Game. 
- please Enter one charachter 
- desired_word  :  _ _ _ _ _ 
- You have 10 chances.
```

John send by telegram one charachter A

text = A , if A correct  Then Send bot to john

```
- Good , Correct Charachter John. 
- please Enter Next charachter 
- desired_word  :  _ _ A _ _ 
- You have 9 chances.
```

ok ?

Now is the time,sara run my bot and start. my bot send for sara in telegram:

```
- Welcome to Guess the word Game. 
- please Enter one charachter 
- desired_word  :  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
- You have 18 chances.
```

Now , john send for bot,next charchater Z , my bot send for john in telegram:

```
- Bad , False Charachter John. 
- please Enter Next charachter 
- desired_word  :  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
- You have 17 chances.
```

!!!!

> The groups telegram done in groups, as well as individually. maybe in group or maybe individually.

Comment: Sounds like both players are using the same instance of the bot object. Make sure a new instance of the bot class is instantiated per user. If it's not obvious to you how to do that you'll need to show more code here so we can see how you're currently creating bots.

Comment: ok @AndyLamb , dont know how . today or Tomorrow edit my code.but you need all codes?Almost all my code this value.

Comment: @AndyLamb almost all my code edit

Comment: no solution , @AndyLamb?

Comment: edit question for u and complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Andy Lamb wrote in a comment, your problem is that you are managing only one "game", so every player interacts with each other.

You must find a way to identify the sender of each message, and manage a "game" for each player.

A game object should be an instance of a class, maintaining all the data which is linked to a single player game (e.g. desired_word, etc). Your `while (true)` loop should look something like this:

```
while (true) {
  var  updates = await bot.MakeRequestAsync(new GetUpdates() { Offset = offset });
  foreach(var update in updates) {
    var sender = GetSender(update);
    var game = RetrieveGameOrInit(sender);

    // ... rest of your processing, but your code is a little messy and
    // you have to figure out how to refactor the processing by yourself
    game.Update(update);

    // do something with game, and possibly remove it if it's over.
  }
}


public string GetSender(UpdateResponseOrSomething update)
{
    // use the Telegram API to find a key to uniquely identify the sender of the message.
    // the string returned should be the unique identifier and it
    // could be an instance of another type, depending upon Telegram
    // API implementation: e.g. an int, or a Guid.
}

private Dictionary<string, Game> _runningGamesCache = new Dictionary<string, Game>();

public Game RetrieveGameOrInit(string senderId)
{
    if (!_runningGamesCache.ContainsKey(senderId))
    {
       _runningGamesCache[senderId] = InitGameForSender(senderId);
    }

    return _runningGamesCache[senderId];
}

/// Game.cs
public class Game
{
  public string SenderId { get; set; }
  public string DesiredWord { get; set; }
  // ... etc

  public void Update(UpdateResponseOrSomething update)
  {
    // manage the update of the game, as in your code.
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @A.Cheiesa , test your answer and comeback. edit question and complete.

Comment: var sender = GetSender(update);

var game = RetrieveGameOrInit(sender);
game.Update(update); 
for what library ? no work my codes Or maybe you just like to have written something that should be done.

Comment: They are just descriptive names for the operations you have to do. I'm going to update the answer with some detail about the inner implementation to do.